# inheriting methods from a Bs4 in my class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to start OOP and decided to rewrite a script in this fashion. A webpage has a box of links that I want to save so I do the following code

```
class webpage(BeautifulSoup):

    def __init__(self, link, html, links):

        self.link = link
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.get(link)
        self.html = driver.page_source
        self.links = []

    def forty_pages(self):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        link_box = soup.find('div', {'id': 'sliderBottom'})
        rest = link_box.find_all('a')
        forty_links = []

        for i in rest:
            try:
                link = i.get('href')
                forty_links.append(link)
            except:
                pass
        self.links.append(x for x in forty_links)

test = webpage(link=root)
test.forty_pages()
```

The problem is that it says

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

which I am confused about as `self.html` should fill itself when the driver returns the string containing html data. Can anyone shed light on this? 
EDIT: I am told that there is no need for composition, but I cannot call the module Bs4 from within the class, so I am stuck as to how to implrment this... for example:

```
class rightmove_page(object):

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link

    def forty_pages(self):
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        html = driver.get(self.link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        print(soup)
```

gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sn/Documents/Projects/House_Prices/class_pased.py", line 21, in <module>
    test.forty_pages()
  File "/home/sn/Documents/Projects/House_Prices/class_pased.py", line 17, in forty_pages
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Where do you think those other parameters will come from? You're calling it directly without them.

Comment: Why do you want to subclass BeautifulSoup here? There doesn't seem to be any reason to do that; you're not using any inherited functionality.

Comment: I want to use some of BeautifulSoups functions definitely, Im just reading up on composition and importing certain Bs4 methods

Comment: But this isn't a case for either composition or inheritance. BeautifulSoup is an external library which you just call from your `forty_pages` method.

Comment: Note also that this code does **not** produce the error you claim; it produces `__init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)`. Please show the actual code, and the full error including traceback.

Comment: hmm youre right, I am going to rewrite this

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, sorted it out its done, just introduces Bs4 in the class methods instead of trying to include the functions in the def **init** part of the class. you are right Daniel Roseman thanks man